# Import class from psCore version

Tags: .net, powershell

I need to use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-5.0) class in PowerShell 5.1.
Is there any ways to do this?

```
$CryptoAlgorithms = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll")
$CryptoAlgorithms.GetTypes()
```

I was trying this code, but got error.

```
$CryptoAlgorithms = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll")
$CryptoAlgorithms.GetTypes()
```

This code gives me empty output.

```
$dll = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\Program Files\dotnet" "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll"

$dll|foreach{
    $b = [Io.File]::ReadAllBytes($_.FullName)
    $CryptoAlgorithms1 = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load($b)
    $CryptoAlgorithms1.GetTypes()
}
```

Comment: Do you have .net core installed?  You probably have .net 4 installed on your box, aesgcm needs .net 5 or .net core.  Powershell version numbers aren't 1:1 with .net versions.

Comment: @Colyn1337 , yes.

Comment: reference the assembly from the .net core location.  Does that give you the class?

Comment: @Colyn1337, answer with code is in the question post.

Comment: Danny, you can't use a powershell 7 library with powershell 5.  Maybe use powershell 7 instead?

Comment: @Colyn1337, so what library can i use?

Comment: You said you have .net core installed.  Load the assembly with the path to the .net core version.

Comment: @Colyn1337, am i correctly understand you with new code? Still not works.